# In Python, how to specify that a Protocol implementer has a specific constructor signature?

Tags: python, constructor, protocols

Is it possible to define that a class needs a specific constructor?

```py
class Constructible(Protocol):

  def __init__(self, i: int):  # how do I do this?
    raise NotImplementedError

  def get_value(self):
    raise NotImplementedError

def map_is(cs: Iterable[Constructible], i: int):
  mapped = tuple(C(i) for C in cs)
  values = tuple(c.get_value() for c in mapped)
  # both the constructor and a member method are used
  return mapped, values

# implementors (omitting __hash__ and __eq__ for brevity)
class X(Constructible):
  def __init__(self, i):
    self.i=i
  def get_value(self):
    return self.i

class Sq(Constructible):
  def __init__(self, i):
    self.i=i
  def get_value(self):
    return self.i * self.i

cs, values = tuple(map_is((X, Sq), 5))
assert values == (5, 25)
```

When specifying it like this, I get

```bash
$ mypy constr.py 
constr.py:12: error: "Constructible" not callable
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is this even possible?  Or should I revert to a factory function `@classmethod def construct(i: int): Self`?

Comment: You have whatever an Enumerable is of _instances of_ Constructible, which aren't callable as they don't implement `__call__`, not of _classes_.

Comment: Thanks, I meant `Iterable`.  They can be a list of classes implementing `Constructible`.  I'll add this to the question.

Comment: If they're classes whose instances are `Constructible` then you have [`Type[Constructible]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type).

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe, that does work!  Yet - I want to express I can both _construct_ and use the `get_value` member (edited the question to reflect that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @jonrsharpe, you do not pass an iterable of `Constructible` instances to `map_is` but an iterable of *classes*. That means that you should define the function that way:

```
def map_is(cs: Iterable[Type[Constructible]], i: int):
  return (C(i) for C in cs)
```

That is enough for mypy to validate the code.

But there is an unrelated problem: you never declared any `__hash__` nor `__equal__` special method. That means that in `assert values == (X(5), Sq(5))` the equality used is the one defined on the `object` class (same as `is`). So after the above fix, the code executes successfully but still raises an `AssertionError`, because the objects do have same value, yet they are distinct objects...

Comment: Yes, indeed - I didn't want to spend time on the equality checks - just providing some motivational pseudo-code would have been better.